# Can I use a WebView to receive push notifications and show them on my Android App using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

Can I use a WebView to receive push notifications and show them on my Android App using Xamarin, and if so, how can I do this? I've been looking and haven't found any direct way of making this happen. I'm trying to basically interface my website into a mobile app, and this appears to be the last thing necessary.

Comment: Do you mean show the content of push notification in the webview? You can save and send the content of notification to the backend and then update the webview with the new content.

Comment: No, I want to basically interface my website into an app, but I am not getting push notifications through it like I would a web browser. I just need to know how to handle them, they are there.

Comment: You want to know how to handle the  push notifications in Android app? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/) is the document.

Comment: No, but thanks. I want to DETECT a notification coming through the webView. like, if the webview gets a notification, how can I handle that?

Comment: Oh, I get it. However I'm not familiar with the notification coming through the webView:(.

Comment: @Velcer, did you ever figure this out? I have the same requirements.

Comment: also looking for an answer to this

Comment: This question basically boils down to if you can have a webview with a serviceworker which is essential for receiving push notifications in PWAs.

It seems that Android have something on intercepting serviceworkers:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ServiceWorkerController